A beautiful property that connects five points located on a circle to the nine point circles
A while ago, while playing with the GeoGebra program, I came across a distinct geometric property, and I would like to know whether it has been previously discovered or not, and also how this complex property can be proven.
The Mathworld website on the page that talks about the nine-dot circle has the following characteristic:
Given four arbitrary points, the four nine-points circles of the triangles formed by taking three points at a times are concurrent

My theorem starts by taking five points that lie on a circle and then creating a point of intersection of the nine point circles for every four of these points. Then we have five new points. Then these five new points will be the vertices of a pentagon similar to the original pentagon and the similarity ratio is $\frac{1}{2}$. Moreover,  Therefore, if we draw the lines connecting the vertices of the original pentagon and their counterparts in the new pentagon, these five lines will converge at one point.

If the original five points did not lie on a single circle, none of these properties would be true: the two pentagons would not be alike, the five lines would not converge at one point and the vertices of the small pentagon would not lie on a single circle.

When the point of intersection of the nine point circles is taken relative to four points, I color that point the same color as the fifth point left from the circle.

Interesting discovery; I don't know if it's novel. ... To prove it, start by showing that, when $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ lie on a circle with its center at the origin, the point of concurrence is $\frac12(A+B+C+D)$.

(1.) Here is another property of this configuration. The line joining any two vertices of one pentagon is parallel to the line that joins the corresponding pair of vertices of the other pentagon.
(2.) Similar set of properties, which you have described for given cyclic pentagon, prevails for any cyclic quadrilateral as well. The quadrilateral made up of the centers of the four nine-point circles of another cyclic quadrilateral is cyclic and they are perspective from a point. The similarity ratio of their corresponding sides is half.

As for the first property that you mentioned, I actually noticed it, but I didn't want to talk about it because it is a direct result of the similarity and the confluence of the connecting lines between opposite points at one pointAs for the second feature, I did not know about it, thanks for mentioning it @YNK

Wow, this is mesmerizing... Have you tried understanding the nature of the point of concurrency in the figure with the pentagons? There's no way it's the centroid of either of the two pentagons, right?

Let $O$ be the center of the circle. It is known (see, for instance, the solution of Problem 13.34 from [Pra]) that $\vec{OE'}=\frac 12\left(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}\right)$ and the similar equalities hold for the other four vectors. (By the way, in the problem is stated only that
given four arbitrary points on a circle, the four nine-points circles of the triangles formed by taking three points at a times are concurrent.) Let $\vec{OO'}=\frac 12\left(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}+\vec{OE}\right)$. Then $\vec{OE'}=\vec{OO'}-\frac 12\vec{OE}$, that is $\vec{O'E'}=-\frac 12\vec{OE}$, and the similar equalities hold for the other four vectors. It easily follows that the five new points indeed are the vertices of a pentagon similar to the original pentagon and the similarity ratio is $\frac 12$. Moreover, the lines connecting the vertices of the original pentagon and their counterparts in the new pentagon have a common point $O''$, such that $\vec{OO''}=\frac 23\vec{OO'}$.
References
[Pra] Viktor Prasolov, Problems in plane and solid geometry, vol. 1, translated and edited by Dimitry Leites.

Is there an English version for  this reference?

@pie Yes. I updated the reference.

But I'm not asking about the centers of the circles, I'm asking about the points of intersection of the circles

@زكرياحسناوي Yes, in my answer each of the points $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, $D'$, and $E'$ is the common point of the respective four nine-points circles, as in your question. Maybe there was something wrong in the Google translation of my answer.
